# Oracle Order By Seconds

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table like the following:

```
TIME   Quantity
200918 122
200919 333
200919 500
181222 32
181223 43
```

The output I would like for the above data is:

```
Time     Quantity
200919   955
181223   75
```

Essentially I want to group based on a tolerance of one second and sum up the quantity taking the latest time. Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: where would an entry like `200917 12` go? or is the data always in pairs of two?

Comment: Please explain what this values of TIME are formatted as.

Comment: Are the values under Time actual time in seconds? or are they just random numbers that you want to sum?

Comment: That would be a separate group

Comment: (HHMMSS) is the format of the time

Comment: Let's just go with the idea that there wouldn't be three different records in the group which spans more than 2 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag()` and cumulative `group by`:

```
select max(time), sum(quantity)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_time < time - 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time
            from t
           ) t
     )
group by grp;
```